# Windows 7 Complete PC Backup - Fails with error code: 0x80070002

Tags: windows-7, backup

While doing a Complete PC Backup in Windows 7 I received dialog reading:

> Windows Backup...error
>
> The backup did not complete
>   successfully.
>
> Open the Backup and Restore Control Panel to view settings

From there I clicked the **Options** button.

> Windows Backup: Troubleshooting Options
>
> Check your backup
>
> Windows Backup encountered invalid MediaID.bin file on the drive where the backup is saved. Restore from a different backup or delete the MediaID.bin file and try to create another backup.  The MediaID.bin file can be found under \MediaID.Bin & \\MediaId.Bin.

I deleted the file in question (MediaID.bin) from X:\ (one of the drives being backedup( and tried the backup again.

Next I was presented with a dialog that read:

> Windows Backups: Troubleshooting Options
>
> Check your backup
>
> The system connot find the file specified.
>
> Try to run backup again
>
> Change backup settings
>
> Backup Time: 2/10/2010 12:17 PM
>   Backup location: FreeAgent Drive (E:)
>   Error code: 0x80070002

Additionally I checked the error log and I found this:

```
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
        <System>
            <Provider Name="Windows Backup" />
            <EventID Qualifiers="0">4104</EventID>
            <Level>2</Level>
            <Task>0</Task>
            <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-02-10T17:17:48.000000000Z" />
            <EventRecordID>5107</EventRecordID>
            <Channel>Application</Channel>
            <Computer>leeand00-PC</Computer>
            <Security />
      </System>
      - <EventData>
            <Data>The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)</Data>
            <Binary>02000780E30500003F0900005B090000420ED1665C2BEE174B64529CB14610EA71000000</Binary>
      </EventData>
</Event>
```

Viewed the following document: 
http://blogs.technet.com/filecab/archive/2008/03/12/common-causes-and-solutions-to-backup-system-restore-and-complete-pc-backup-problems-updated.aspx
searched for 0x80070002 and tried and follow the directions...

I noticed that none of the profiles was missing a ProfileImagePath, I also noticed that the people commenting on the page said that they weren't missing it either.

I'm currently trying the backup again, but this time I unchecked all of the user's profiles and opted only to backup the two drives X: and C: on to E:\

I'll let you know what happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just found out that I have two users on my system that have been created, but that I haven't logged in with yet.
I think this may be the problem, as when I did log in as those users, I checked back in the registry again at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList and there were two more profile entries created there after I logged in with those users, so I have to wonder if this won't fix the problem.